# JavaScript Select whole link after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, anchor

How to select whole link after click on this?
And later use `document.getSelection();`

My code doesn't work:

```
$('a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $(this).select();
    //document.getElementByTagName('a').select(); // Doesn't work too

    return false;
});
```

Comment: A bit confusing what you are looking for. Can you post html to be more clear?

Comment: @Sergio: Highlight link after clicked

Comment: Follow Barmar's link. `.select` only works on form controls.

Comment: I create something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/WxHBn/, but each next click on link works only when before click outside

Comment: Works correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/WxHBn/3/